# Android drawing lines with margin

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, layer-list

So, I managed to create a shape (rectangle) with only one side. Now, I want that one side to have margin right and margin left. Right now it looks like this:

[image: Right now it looks like this:]

and this is how it is supposed to look like(don't mind colors):

[image]

Now, I have a code for the line:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:left="-55dp"
    android:right="-55dp"
    android:top="-55dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <stroke
            android:width="5dp"
            android:color="@color/text" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

How to achieve this?

Layout for the textviews.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/picture_activity_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/picture_activity_take_new"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_text_line"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_profilepicture_takephoto"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding"
            android:text="Take a new picture"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/large_text_size"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/picture_activity_select_from_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_profilepicture_addphoto"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding"
            android:text="Select new from gallery"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/large_text_size"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/picture_activity_remove_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_profilepicture_delete"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding"
            android:text="Remove photo"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/large_text_size"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why shape is required here?

Comment: make a view with height = 1dp, 2dp whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a recyclerview. For a recyclerview you would need to have a single row layout.

```
<LinearLayout>
    height, width, id

    <TextView>
         width = "match_parent"
         height, id

    <LinearLayout>
         android:id="@+id/line"
         android:height="2dp"
         android:width="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginLeft="whatever_you_need"
         android:layout_marginRight="whatever_you_need"
         android:background="some_color" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So here, you don't have to add the line manually everytime
There is one issue, i.e. the line will come below your last row. I believe you would like to remove it.

In the adapter

```
String[] itemList = {"Take a new Picture", "Select from Gallery",...};
```

In your viewholder class in the recyclerview adapter:

```
line = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.line);
```

In your onBindViewHolder for the recyclerview. Here we identify the last row and then hide the underline.

```
if(position == itemList.length - 1){  //position starts from 0
    holder.line.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Now this will look as you desire

Comment: recyclerview would serve you better as it is flexible and has all + more functionality... if you still want to make it hardcoded then the linearlayout part of the solution still holds, just repeat it as many times you want